# What to do with many good incomplete answers?

Tags: discussion, questions

There are many good answers to my question, but none of them is complete. So I can't accept any. The perfect answer would be created by merging many answers that are already written. What should I do? Create a community wiki answer containing parts of each of the answers and then accept it? Leave the question without any accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> merging many answers that are already written. What should I do? Create a community wiki answer containing parts of each of the answers and then accept it? Leave the question without any accepted answer?

Sure, you could add your own answer summarizing all of them (with appropriate references).

Additionally you could make that answer a community wiki contribution, if you feel you shouldn't gain the rep for a compilation of things other users contributed.

Here's a great example from Stack Overflow:

- [**What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)